# HTML select field rendering takes time

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, performance

I am currently working on an `angularJS` application. I have an `HTML` form with around 40 controls. All other controls are rendering fine except the select fields. There are around 16 select fields on my page, and this select fields is an `angular directive`. When I say select field is not rendering fine, I mean it loads however it first stretches to a bigger size and then comes to it's size specified in `CSS`. Hence the rendering is not smooth. Any particular reason why my select fields are stretching and then comes to a normal size? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Will you please share your code so we can help you ?

Comment: Thanks Vineet, did you mean css code?

Comment: can you post all the relevant code?

Answer (score 2):

The possible reason I see why this happens is that the browser loads your select elements before it finishes loading your css files or angularjs file. Please try declaring the width of the select field using inline css on your directive template.

```
<select style="width:100px"><option>Option 1</option></select>
```

Another solution that you may try is using the "elem" parameter in your directive declaration.

```
app.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '<select><option>Option 1</option></select>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {          
      elem.css('width', '100px');
    }
  };
});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, however the css and js files are getting loaded completely through index.html and this form is getting rendered on an action on index.html.

Comment: Also, this happens in IE only.

Comment: I see.. but have you tried the sol'n already? Also, I don't doubt that the css and js files are being loaded. The question is.. which is being loaded first... because if your select fields are being loaded before your css file then they won't certainly have the styling right on the bat.. that's why I suggested the inline method because the template will be evaluated by the angularjs first before it returns it on the DOM.. Hope this helps! :D

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to slower response from database. All 16 drop down data coming from DB correct. You can optimized your angular script.

Comment: Sorry to not have informed this in my question, I tried with a different select directive and rendering was quite smooth. I think it is related to css.